# kendo treeview checkbox - parent node check - change event on every checkbox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a **2-level Kendo UI Treeview** with parent and children nodes.
When I check a parent node, all children nodes (including parent) are automatically checked.

Now **I want to send an event with current tree selection** state. 
The problem is when I try to do it in **dataSource.change** method because it **fires on every checkbox selection separately** (1 parent node + 3 children nodes = 4 change events). This is what the code looks like:

```
treeView.data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.bind("change", function() {
    alert('event fired!');
});
```

I've created a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ydyfQ/)

Is there another event to attach to to have only one event fired after all checkboxes are updated?
Or maybe there is a way to group all those 'change' events and fire just one instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended with this solution:

```
tree.data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.bind("change", function() {
        treeView = tree.data("kendoTreeView");
        checkedNodes = [];
    checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
    if (!timeoutSet) {
        setTimeout(fireCheckboxChangeOnce, 50);//fires only one event when parent checkbox checks all the children
        timeoutSet = true;
    }
});
```

Only the first event creates a delayed call to function (using *setTimeout()*).
All the remaining "change" events only modify the *checkedNodes* parameter.

*fireCheckboxChangeOnce* function also clears the *timeoutSet* flag.

Comment: Thanks - this works but ideally we should look for a solution without timeouts