# Angular - Kendo treeview checkbox change event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-datasource

I am trying to implement the checkbox change event using angular but seeing the event firing multiple times when a checkbox is clicked.

I have created a [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/yDNF85J7XiVAlFT9z0uK) for this, please help. Ideally it should be fired only once.

```
$scope.treeOptions = {
  checkboxes: {
    checkChildren: true
  },
  dataBound: function(e) {
    $scope.attachChangeEvent(e);

  }

};
```

Event change code:

```
 $scope.attachChangeEvent = function(e) {

  var dataSource = e.sender.dataSource;
  // issue : change event is getting called multiple times for every click on checkbox
  dataSource.bind("change", function(e) {
    var selectedNodes = 0;

    var checkedNodes = [];

    $scope.checkedNodeIds(dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);


    for (var i = 0; i < checkedNodes.length; i++) {
      var nd = checkedNodes[i];
      if (nd.checked) {
        selectedNodes++;
      }
    }
    // check the console - this is called multiple times for one checkbox click
    console.log(selectedNodes);
  });
};
```

Is there another event to attach to to have only one event fired after all checkboxes are updated? Or maybe there is a way to group all those 'change' events and fire just one instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataBound` event is triggered multiple times because you're dealing with a hierarchical data source (each child DS triggers the event, and it bubbles up). As a result, you're binding the change handler multiple times.
You should instead bind the change event from your `initTree` method; snippet:

```
var knobj = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: arrayObj
});

//setting heirarchial data to scope
$scope.treeObj = knobj;
$scope.attachChangeEvent();
```

([updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sxZw1JDFM8tXONJsB5SK?p=preview))

Alternatively, you can use the `dataBound` event and check `e.node`, which is apparently `undefined` for the last time dataBound is triggered ([demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/igTRpmqWiH0za7meFQ8L?p=preview)):

```
dataBound: function(e) {
    if (!e.node) {
        $scope.attachChangeEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lars - Thanks for response. There seems to be some more issue - the page on refresh is calling the attach event thrice and also sometimes the event is firing twice after doing some iterations.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - can you change the demo to illustrate or give steps to reproduce? The data source change event will get triggered twice if you check all children of a parent - in that case, the parent will automatically be set to "checked" which triggers the second event

Comment: OK, I think I know what you mean - the treeview makes changes to the data source when it initializes, which triggers the change event; I added another alternative to my answer

Comment: Right! but there is still some issue where selecting - sometimes the event is firing twice ( i added a timeout and it works fine ) - ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972838/kendo-treeview-checkbox-parent-node-check-change-event-on-every-checkbox . Anyways Thanks you Lars - appreciate your help.